# Converting timestamp/Zone to R datetime

Tags: r, timestamp-with-timezone

I have the following timestamp:
`"03-APR-06 12.41.00.000000000 PM US/CENTRAL"`
and need to convert it to an R compatible timestamp.

I have tried:

```
structure(df2$ACTION_IN_DTTM_TZ,class=c('POSIXct'))
parse_date_time(df2$ACTION_IN_DTTM_TZ, "abdHMSzY")
strptime(df2$ACTION_IN_DTTM_TZ,format='%d/%b/%Y:%H:%M:%S:%p:%Z')
```

and all of them generated NAs

```
structure(df2$ACTION_IN_DTTM_TZ,class=c('POSIXct'))
parse_date_time(df2$ACTION_IN_DTTM_TZ, "abdHMSzY")
strptime(df2$ACTION_IN_DTTM_TZ,format='%d/%b/%Y:%H:%M:%S:%p:%Z')
```

I would like this:
`2012-08-10 04:42:47`

Any suggestions are greatly appreciated! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I did something like:

```
a <-  "03-APR-06 12.41.00.000000000 PM US/CENTRAL"
b <- (substr(a,1,18))
c <- as.POSIXct(b,format='%d-%b-%y %H.%M.%S')
```

Comment: Hi Pietro,, Thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

Package `lubridate` provides functionality for this. I extracted the timezone with a simple str_extract command.

```
library(lubridate)
library(stringr)
timestamp <- "03-APR-06 12.41.00.000000000 PM US/CENTRAL"
as_datetime(timestamp,tz=str_extract(timestamp,"\\S*$"))
[1] "2003-04-06 00:41:00 CST"

#without lubridate
strptime(strsplit(timestamp," \\S*$")[[1]][1],format="%y-%b-%d %I.%M.%S.%OS %p",tz=str_extract(timestamp,"\\S*$"))
```

Comment: I get the following error when I used that: Error in C_force_tz(time, tz = tzone, roll) : 
  CCTZ: Unrecognized output timezone: "US/CENTRAL"

Comment: Very interesting, runs for me without a problem. I'm using `stringr_1.3.1` and `lubridate_1.7.4`. //EDIT: I just restarted my R session and only loaded these two packages. It still works fine, so maybe try to restart your session?

Comment: I am running it on a big cluster..Thank you though!

Comment: I know there was a bug in lubridate a while ago, that would throw errors like that sometimes. So maybe you have an older version installed on your cluster

Comment: I edited a base solution to the problem, hopefully this works for you.